# Shade map v2 with a grey color outside a circle

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I know  how to draw a circle at a certain location on the map and give it a fill color. However, How can I do the opposite? Basically draw a circle but give a color to the area outside the circle.

Or in other words, how can I shade the whole map with a  color (say grey) so I can draw a circle with transparent fill color?

Any suggestion is helpful

Thank you

Comment: No one knows the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the stroke color?

> Stroke Width
>   The width of the circle's outline in screen pixels. The width is constant and independent of the camera's zoom level. The default value is 10.
>
> Stroke Color
>   The color of the circle outline in ARGB format, the same format used by Color. The default value is black (0xff000000).`

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Stroke color is the outline color of the circle . I want the whole map shaded outside the circle not just the circle perimeter

Comment: Oh, ok, now I see what you want.
well, if you draw a circle you cannot manage to change what is outside it.
The only thing you can do is to set a custom TileOverlay that for each tiles draw a semitransparent bitmap for each tile, so that bitmap will be a sort of shade. The problem here is that if you want to have the shade only outside of the circle you have to do a lot of checks when creating the tiles INSIDE of the circle (clipping the tile with the circle area, but the two are in different contexts..)

Comment: I see. I wish it was easier than this :S.. I will accept the answer being the only one correct :) Thanks though